# Mysql Error while piping database to different server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh

I have a strange error here. The command I am executing is this:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppass kodi_video119 | mysql -h192.168.178.73 -u kodi -ppass kodi_video119
```

When I execute it over SSH it all works fine, but when I save it to a file and execute this file I get the following error:

```
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
'RROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'kodi_video119
mysqldump: Got errno 11 on write
```

I can't find any results using google on that error number. The user is allowed to write and it all works fine when I execute it direcly from SSH. But using the same SSH session (as root user) just executing the command embedded in the file it does not work.

Whats going wrong here? I created the file using nano and saved it using nano. Then chmod +x and execute ./test

Comment: it tells you clearly you **don't** have a database named `kodi_video119`. this is usually the sign that you are on the false database

Comment: Add options to mysqldump which will put all CREATE statements needed for restoring (and maybe according dropping option).

Comment: The database exists on both servers. It is writing it out with that ‘ sign in the Output though…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you use `mysqldump DB`, the output includes table-creation statements, but no `CREATE DATABASE` statement. It just assumes you have created an empty schema first.

So you could do this to create the schema first:

```
mysqladmin -h192.168.178.73 create kodi_video119
mysqldump kodi_video119 | mysql -h192.168.178.73 kodi_video119
```

(I left out the -u and -p options for brevity)

Alternatively, you can use the `-B` option, aka `--databases`. This option allows you to specify one or more databases, and the output includes `CREATE DATABASE` statements for each one before it then creates and populates tables. You can use it with a single database argument:

```
mysqldump -B kodi_video119 | mysql -h192.168.178.73 kodi_video119
```

Comment: Thats giving me the exact same error. The database exists on the server and the command Runs perfectly fine when executed in the SSH Shell but refuses to work in a script. Any suggestions to that behaviour?

Comment: Have you shown exactly how you invoke this command? The presence of the extra `'` character is suspicious.

Comment: Well I put that exact command in an empty file created with nano. Than I save it without file extention and make it executable using chmod +x filename. Than I execut it with ./filename as the root user. I don't see anything wrong with that. Encoding must be fine I suggest and I can't see any typos ...

Comment: I started from scratch now again and like it sometimes is ... now it works. You answer helped me a lot. Thanks for that!

Comment: Sure, I've been there too. Starting over from scratch is one way of eliminating a mistake we keep overlooking. :-)